# finding if a column has multiple classes in it data.table

Tags: r, data.table, coercion

I've got a massive data.table so I can't see all my entries in the columns.

I want to convert a column, which is apparently of class character to numeric, however, when I use as.numeric(col_name), i get the warning "NAs introduced by coercion". Before I do anything else, I was wondering whether I can find out which entries in the column are not characters or what is causing the issue.

I do str on the data.table which gives:

```
    Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  57042881 obs. of  21 variables:
 $ V1 : int  142466 1265 142510 199933 143297 13548 143605 15194 143894 16701 ...
 $ V2 : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ V3 : int  20150702 20160316 20150702 20160316 20150703 20160324 20150704 20160327 20150704 20160331 ...
 $ V4 : int  14 17 15 6 16 17 9 20 14 15 ...
 $ V5 : chr  "2015-07-02 14:50:00" "2016-03-16 17:40:00" "2015-07-02 15:58:00" "2016-03-16 06:20:00" ...
 $ V6 : int  33547 25523 33547 25523 33547 25523 33547 25523 33547 25523 ...
 $ V7 : num  42.9 33.9 53.8 65.3 35.7 ...
 $ V8 : int  2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ V9 : num  60 34.5 75.3 66.5 50 ...
 $ V10: num  5.46 3.14 6.84 6.05 4.55 3.3 0.71 2.18 3.11 1.82 ...
 $ V11: chr  "1.271732" "0.926145" "1.271883" "0.926295" ...
 $ V12: num  1.4 1.02 1.4 1.02 1.4 ...
 $ V13: int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ V14: int  0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ V16: chr  "ULP" "ULP" "ULP" "ULP" ...
 $ V17: POSIXct, format: "2015-07-02 14:50:00" "2016-03-16 17:40:00" "2015-07-02 15:58:00" "2016-03-16 06:20:00" ...
 $ V18: Date, format: "2015-07-02" "2016-03-16" "2015-07-02" "2016-03-16" ...
 $ V19: int  2015 2016 2015 2016 2015 2016 2015 2016 2015 2016 ...
 $ V20: int  7 3 7 3 7 3 7 3 7 3 ...
 $ V21: int  2 16 2 16 3 24 4 27 4 31 ...
```

And then I want to convert V11 to numeric.

```
dt_2 <- dt[, V11 := as.numeric(V11)]
Warning message:
In eval(expr, envir, enclos) : NAs introduced by coercion
```

Why am I getting this warning? Is it because there are types other than character in column V11? If so, how do I find the values in column V11 which aren't character?

Thanks!

Comment: It means that you have some non-numeric elements in 'V11' which gets converted to NA by coercing to `numeric`.  It is a friendly warning to check your original dataset column for anything fishier.  You could investigate this by doing `i1 <- is.na(as.numeric(dt$V11)); head(dt$V11[i1])` to see what values are there the original column that gets converted to `NA`

Comment: I meant the investigation stuff before doing the `:=`

Comment: Thanks for that. I ran your suggestion, but it doesn't show me where the differences are, it just shows a whole bunch of NAs. Is there anyway for me to be able to see what the entry was before it was coerced to NA?

Comment: It is because you already converted the column with `V11 :=`.`  Try it by reading on a fresh session (so as not to mess up with memory) and then do as I commented earlier before doing the `:=`.  If it takes too much time, then you can still read it `fread("yourfile.csv", select = 11)` assuming it is the 11th column

Comment: Try running: `dt$V11[is.na(as.numeric(dt$V11)]`  this will make the NAs and then subset the failing rows.

Comment: @Dave2e This is the same comment I said to the OP before

Comment: @akrun, thanks for that. Once i run the code i find there are lots of "null" s. Am i right in thinking that R won't converting the null to numeric and instead gives me an NA?

Comment: @Gin_Salmon, in that case, we can do `na.strings = "null" and this will read it correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the dataset is really big, it may be better to read the single column **again** in a fresh session (as the OP already replaced the column 'V11' by assigning (`:=`) it to itself.

```
library(data.table)
dt1 <- fread("yourfile.csv", select = 11)
```

By using the `select` argument, we can read the specific column.  Then, we convert that column to `numeric`, check the NA elements with `is.na` too create a logical `vector`.

```
i1 <- is.na(as.numeric(dt1[[1]]))
```

Subset the column based on the 'i1'

```
v1 <- dt1[[1]][i1]
```

and then do the investigation.

**after 1 hour**

and based on the investigation, the OP mentioned that the values were `"null"`.  In that case, we can use `na.strings = "null"` in `fread` and it should replace the "null" with `NA` and we get the correct `class` (assuming there are no other non-numeric strings)

```
dt2 <- fread("yourfile.csv", na.strings = "null")
```